# Remove column names in a DataFrame

Tags: r, sparkr

In sparkR I have a DataFrame `data`.
When I type `head(data)` we get this output

```
  C0      C1               C2         C3
1 id user_id foreign_model_id machine_id 
2  1   3145                4         12 
3  2   4079                1          8 
4  3   1174                7          1    
5  4   2386                9          9    
6  5   5524                1          7
```

I want to remove `C0,C1,C2,C3` because they give me problems later one. For example when I use the `filter`     function:

```
filter(data,data$machine_id==1)
```

can't run because of this.

---

I have read the data like this

```
data <- read.df(sqlContext, "/home/ole/.../data", "com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

Comment: I think you have read the data frame wrong. You want to delete the column names of the data frame and make row 1 as your new column name, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Then can't you do: `colnames(data) = data[1, ]` and `data = data[-1, ]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SparkR made the header into the first row and gave the DataFrame a new header because the default for the header option is "false". Set the header option to header="true" and then you won't have to handle with this problem.

```
data <- read.df(sqlContext, "/home/ole/.../data", "com.databricks.spark.csv", header="true")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
colnames(data) <- unlist(data[1,])
data <- data[-1,]
> data
#  id user_id foreign_model_id machine_id
#2  1    3145                4         12
#3  2    4079                1          8
#4  3    1174                7          1
#5  4    2386                9          9
#6  5    5524                1          7
```

If you wish, you can add `rownames(data) <- NULL` to correct for the row numbers after the deletion of the first row.

After this manipulation, you can select rows that correspond to certain criteria, like

```
subset(data, data$machine_id==1)
#  id user_id foreign_model_id machine_id
#4  3    1174                7          1
```

In base `R`, the function `filter()` suggested in the OP is part of the `stats` namespace and is usually reserved for the analysis of time series.

**data**

```
data <- structure(list(C0 = structure(c(6L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
      .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "id"), class = "factor"), 
       C1 = structure(c(6L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("1174", "2386", 
      "3145", "4079", "5524", "user_id"), class = "factor"), 
      C2 = structure(c(5L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L), 
     .Label = c("1", "4", "7", "9", "foreign_model_id"), class = "factor"), 
      C3 = structure(c(6L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 3L), 
      .Label = c("1", "12", "7", "8", "9", "machine_id"), class = "factor")), 
     .Names = c("C0", "C1", "C2", "C3"), class = "data.frame", 
     row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Comment: why do you `unlist` to obtain the colnames? Wouldn't `colnames(data) <- data[1,]` do it?

Comment: @Sotos Did you try it? The default setting in reading files is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`, which is why your suggestion doesn't work, at least not on my computer. When I use your code, the colnames are "6", "6", "5", "6", which corresponds to the level number (within the columns) of the entries in the first row.

Comment: ahh...ok, I see. It needs to be a character for it to work without `unlist`. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
names <- c()
for (i in seq(along = names(data))) {
   names <- c(names, toString(data[1,i]))
}

names(data) <- names
data <- data[-1,]
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply can't use the answers because in sparkR it can't run: `object of type 'S4' is not subsettable`. I solved the problem this way, however, I think there is a better way to solve it.

```
data <- withColumnRenamed(data, "C0","id")
data <- withColumnRenamed(data, "C1","user_id")
data <- withColumnRenamed(data, "C2","foreign_model_id")
data <- withColumnRenamed(data, "C3","machine_id")
```

And now I can successfully use the `filter` function as I want to.