# How to remove column and row labels from data frame?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a data frame

```
                          Dim 1       Dim 2
Low Acceleration    0.615631233 0.000141725
Medium Acceleration 0.531160937 0.288548459
High Acceleration   0.001130792 0.751136141
```

I want to remove both the column labels as well as row labels, how can i achieve this ? I tried using `rownames(abc) <- c()` and `abc <- abc[,-1]`, where abc is my data frame.

I need something like this

```
  0.615631233  0.000141725
  0.531160937  0.288548459
  0.001130792  0.751136141
```

Comment: Why do want to remove column/row names?  If you don't want them, then why not just don't use them?

Comment: i had to apply MCA on my given dataset and then i want to extract the co ordinate values obtained from the results for further application. So i need to remove column names and just require the dimension values as a co ordinate system . (Dim1 , Dim 2)

Comment: I guess you need to give us sample data via `dput()` and the code where row and column names are in the way, otherwise we won't understand your problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you delete the header in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175602/how-do-you-delete-the-header-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: I think similar questions are here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35840073/remove-column-names-in-a-dataframe and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175602/how-do-you-delete-the-header-in-a-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You were thinking right. 
`rownames(abc) <- c()`
`colnames(abc)<- c()` will work

```
df<- data.frame(col=c(1.34,3.45,2,56), row.names = c("a","b","c","d"))
df
    col
a  1.34
b  3.45
c  2.00
d 56.00

rownames(df)<- c()
colnames(df)<- c()
df

1  1.34
2  3.45
3  2.00
4 56.00
```

Comment: Probably converting to a matrix would be better. data.frames without column names, or with the duplicate column names are ill advised. Also, the canonical method for removing row names is `row.names(df) <- NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @imo, it's better to convert your `dataframe` to a matrix if you're going to reference the columns and rows by index, especially when it's all numeric. You can just do this:

```
mat = as.matrix(df)
dimnames(mat) = NULL
```

**Result:**

```
> mat
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 0.615631233 0.000141725
[2,] 0.531160937 0.288548459
[3,] 0.001130792 0.751136141
```

**Data:**

```
df = read.table(text = "rownames Dim1 Dim2
                LowAcceleration 0.615631233 0.000141725
                MediumAcceleration 0.531160937 0.288548459
                HighAcceleration 0.001130792 0.751136141", header = TRUE, row.names = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to make it is to use `unname()` and `as.matrix()`, i.e.,

```
mat <- unname(as.matrix(df))
```

such that

```
> mat
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 0.615631233 0.000141725
[2,] 0.531160937 0.288548459
[3,] 0.001130792 0.751136141
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're after a more efficient numerical structure (i.e., a Numpy array), use [`pd.as_matrix()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html), which will return a Numpy array of arrays:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; import numpy as np

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,2),columns=['A','B'],index=['p','q','r','s'])

In [3]: print(df)
          A         B
p -1.284468 -0.264533
q -0.347832  0.026523
r -0.349578  0.681883
s  0.004477 -0.738606

In [4]: df.as_matrix()
Out[4]:
array([[-1.28446781, -0.26453299],
       [-0.34783207,  0.02652279],
       [-0.34957842,  0.68188282],
       [ 0.00447653, -0.73860575]])

In [5]: print(type(df.as_matrix()))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: ::facepalm:: Never mind, your question was about R, not Pandas.